# Change a variable in the current sbt task scope

Tags: scala, sbt

This compiles, but it doesn't add the `scalacOptions` to the `compile` task. What's the correct way to do this?

```
compileWall in ThisBuild := Def.task {
  scalacOptions += "-Xfatal-warnings"
  (compile in Compile).value
}.value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBT settings is immutable in the **Runtime**, so we can't update `scalacOptions` in the customize `Task`.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Full-Def.html#Reminder%3A+it%E2%80%99s+all+immutable

but There is a way to achieve change `scalacOptions` in the customize `Task` by **creating the customize config** and bind the `scalacOptions` in this **config**, like:

```
lazy val MyCompile = config("MyCompile") extend Compile // customize config: MyCompile
configs(MyCompile) //configs 
inConfig(MyCompile)(Defaults.configTasks) //inConfig and append the Defaults.configTasks

val compileWall = taskKey[Unit]("compileWall")

compileWall in ThisBuild := {
  (compile in MyCompile).value
}

scalacOptions in MyCompile := Seq("-Xfatal-warnings") // bind the scalacOptions in customize config.
```